How to check what data is received by APNS sent from backend?
I am working as iOS developer and now working to handle the Apple Push Notification Payload contains custom tag like this:

{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
    "title": "Title of APN",
    "body": "Body of APN"
    },
    "badge": 32
},
"context": {
            "site_name": "***",
            "path": "***",
            "uid": "***",
            "site_id": "example.com",
            "type": "***",
            "entity_id": "***"
        }
}

The notification with the above Payload format is send from the Drupal backend.
The problem is that while receiving the notification and Log the userInfo dictionary in delegate method:
I see only this part:

"aps": {
    "alert": {
    "title": "Title of APN",
    "body": "Body of APN"
    },
    "badge": 32
}

And the custom tags "context" part is missing.
Is there any mechanism in Apple site to check the data received by the APNS from the Drupal backend?
Thanks in advance!

There is missing comma after aps's closing brace. May be that's the reason, why APNS server is sending just part of JSON, because JSON is invalid.

In the Drupal code the Payload like this:
{
"aps": {
"alert": {
"title": "Title of APN",
"body": "Body of APN"
},
"badge": 32
},
"context": {
"site_name": "",
"path": "",
"uid": "",
"site_id": "example.com",
"type": "",
"entity_id": "***"
}
}
I left the comma to type here.
